# C# DataTable Add Column DuplicateNameException

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to add a column to a datatable within a dataset in C# (the dataset is read from an XML document).  It seems that, if I name the column, I receive a DuplicateNameException when trying to add it.  If I leave the column unnamed, it gets added to the datatable.  It doesn't seem to matter what the name of the column actually is; just whether the Datatable.ColumnName property is defined.

Here is the relevant code block (xR is a previously defined XmlTextReader, and this is all in a while xR.Read() loop):

```
xR.ReadToDescendant(this.calDataTag);
XmlReader xS = xR.ReadSubtree();
ds.ReadXml(xS);

foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
   if (dt.Columns.Contains("offset"))
   {
      if (dt.TableName == "Single")
      {
         DataColumn c1 = new DataColumn();
         c1.Caption = "TipType";
         c1.ColumnName = "whatever";
         dt.Columns.Add(c1);
      }

      foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
         foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
         {
            outString.Add("Table: " + dt.TableName.ToString() + " Column: " + dc.ColumnName.ToString() + " RowVal: " + dr[dc] + " " + dt.Columns.Contains("whatever")); 
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

Interestingly, the dt.Columns.Contains("whatever") part of the string always returns False.  So this is not a true DuplicateNameException.  I'm sure I'm just implementing the Columns.Add method improperly.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Bottom line, you can't have 2 columns with the same name. You'll never reach `dt.Columns.Contains("whatever")` to see `true` because your code breaks at `dt.Columns.Add(c1);`

Comment: I did not get it, but you add 'Whatever' column in table and then in next time if both the conditions in your first foreach are true you are again adding 'Whatever' in table.

Comment: @Kashif - I'm apparently trying to add the same column to the same table multiple times.  Pretty rookie mistake.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to me you are checking the wrong conditions or at least you are not covering yourself enough, instead of doing this:

```
if (dt.Columns.Contains("offset"))
   {
      if (dt.TableName == "Single")
```

why don't do:

```
if (dt.TableName == "Single" && !dt.Columns.Contains("whatever") && dt.Columns.Contains("offset"))
{
  var c1 = new DataColumn();
  c1.Caption = "TipType";
  c1.ColumnName = "whatever";
  dt.Columns.Add(c1);
}
```

then you have to put your `outString` generation wherever it fits, this code should at least be easier to debug and you can find what is going on quicker.

Comment: this fixed it.  You're right; it's a combination of this fix and what the two commenters above said.